# How to call back function which consist of other function?

Tags: python, namespaces

I'm trying to write application with Python and Tkinter. Which would perform calculations consisting of few functions taking each other outputs as arguments. And would show last function result to user

On back-end is seems that code is working correctly, as by example below 50 is printed as expected. But I do not manage to get button functioning.

```
import tkinter as tk

main_window = tk.Tk()

a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5

def function (a,b,c):
    return a+b+c

def sumation (d):
    sum = function (a,b,c)
    return sum + d

def multiplication (e):
    return sumation (d) * e

def callback():
   print (multiplication (e))

print (multiplication (e))

b = tk.Button(text="click me", command=callback)
b.pack()

main_window.mainloop()
```

I would expect each time button is pressed that 50 would be printed but but I’m receiving this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:.../Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/Program.py", line 24, in callback
    print (multiplication (e))
```

Is it due to reason that one function consists of other functions output? As with one function it seems to work correctly. If yes is there are any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: You chopped off the part of the traceback that contains the actual error message - but presumably it's related to the fact that by the time the button has been clicked, `b` has been redefined from being 2 to being a Button.  So `function()` is trying to calculate `1+Button+3`...

Comment: Thank you very much, changing b = tk.Button(text="click me", command=callback) to btn = tk.Button(text="click me", command=callback). Solved the issue.

Comment: Side note do not name your functions `function`. This is a built in name and should not be overwritten.